# ColdFusion hmac() returns different values with toBase64 and binaryEncode

Tags: coldfusion, binary, hex, sha256, hmac

I am attempting to use ColdFusion's [hmac()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-h-im/hmac.html) function to calculate an HMAC value using `binaryEncode(binaryObj,'Base64')` instead of [toBase64()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-t-z/tobase64.html) since that function is deprecated. It works perfectly with `toBase64()` but not with `binaryEncode()`. The docs are not very informative. Can someone help me understand why I cannot get the same value using `binaryEncode`?

From what I understand, the `hmac()` function returns the results in hexadecimal format. `binaryEncode()` expects a binary value, so the`hmac()` results must be first converted from hex to binary, before it can be converted to base64.

```
<cfset string = "1234567890" />
<cfset secretKey = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" />
<!--- Get Hex results from HMAC() --->
<cfset hmacHex = hmac(string,secretKey,'HMACSHA256') />
<!--- Decode the binary value from hex --->
<cfset hmacAsBinary = binaryDecode(hmacHex,'hex') />
<!--- Convert binary object to Base64 --->
<cfset hmacBase64 = binaryEncode(hmacAsBinary, 'base64') />
<cfoutput>
    <!--- incorrect hmac signature --->
    hmacBase64: #hmacBase64#<br>
    <!--- correct hmac signature --->
    toBase64: #toBase64(hmac(string,secretKey,'HMACSHA256'))#<br>
</cfoutput>
```

The results are:

```
hmacBase64: VEVGNnqg9b0eURaDCsA4yIOz5c+QtoJqIPInEZOuRm4=
toBase64: NTQ0NTQ2MzY3QUEwRjVCRDFFNTExNjgzMEFDMDM4Qzg4M0IzRTVDRjkwQjY4MjZBMjBGMjI3MTE5M0FFNDY2RQ==
```

One thing I noticed is the results are much longer when using `toBase64()`. I can't seem to figure out why I can't use `binaryEncode()`. However, I would like to, since `toBase64()` is being deprecated. Any insight is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update based on comments:**

Well using `ToBase64(Hmac(...))` is *not* the correct way to convert a hex string to base64 ;-) However, it sounds like the API requires something other than a straight conversion.  If so, just do what the `ToBase64(hmac(...))` code is doing. ie Decode the hex string as UTF8 and re-encode it as base64:

`matchingResult = binaryEncode(charsetDecode(hmacHex, "utf-8"), "base64")`

---

**Short answer:**

The two methods are encoding totally different values. That is why the results do not match. The correct way to convert the hex string to base64 is using [BinaryEncode/Decode()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-a-b/binaryencode.html).

**Longer answer:**

> `<!--- correct hmac signature --->`
>   `toBase64: #toBase64(hmac(string,secretKey,'HMACSHA256'))#<br>`

Actually that is *not* the correct way to convert hex to base64.

Hexadecimal and Base64 are just different ways of representing a *binary* value. In order to get the same results, the two methods need to start with the same binary. In this case, are actually encoding totally different values. Hence the difference in the results.

With a hexadecimal string, each byte is represented by two characters. So the *binary* will be *half* the size of the original string. In the case of HMAC(HMACSHA256), the resulting hex string is 64 characters long. So the *binary* value should be 32 bytes. To obtain the correct binary value, the string must be decoded *as hex*:

```
original string length = #len(hmacHex)#
binary size = #arrayLen(binaryDecode(hmacHex, "hex"))#
```

The problem with ToBase64 is that it decodes the string incorrectly. It treats the input as UTF8 and decodes the characters in the string *individually*. So the binary value is double the size it should be. Notice it is 64 bytes, instead of 32? That is why the final string is longer as well.

```
UTF8 binary size = #arrayLen(charsetDecode(hmacHex, "utf-8"))# 
ToBase64 binary size = #arrayLen(binaryDecode(toBase64(hmacHex), "base64"))#
```

So again, the two methods produce different results because they are encoding totally different values. However, strictly speaking, only the first method is correct. To re-encode a hex string as base64 use [binaryEncode/binaryDecode](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-a-b/binaryencode.html):

```
correctResult = binaryEncode(binaryDecode(hmacHex, "hex"), "base64")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Leigh. While I can't say what is right or wrong with certainty, I can say that the results themselves seem off using binaryEncode/binaryDecode with CF's hmac() function. I think something is incorrect in ColdFusion or the way I have it converting from Hex to Binary to Base64. Our payment processor does integrations with thousands of companies and it matches the toBase64() results. Also, we set it up in PHP using hash_hmac and base64_encode, and it matches CF's toBase64() results. Those two things make it seem like the problem is with binaryEncode/Decode w/ cf's hmac().

Comment: I should note that I was able to get a matching hmac() signature value using HMACSHA1, however, using HMACSHA256 does not match our payment provider nor PHP as expected.

Comment: Well the individual rules for a payment processor and what they require is a totally different story ;-) However, that is *not* the correct way to convert from hex to base64. That said, if that is what their API requires, just do what I explained above. Decode the hex as UTF8 and re-encode it as base64: `binaryEncode(charsetDecode(hmacHex, "utf-8"), "base64")`

Comment: Thanks Leigh, your answer is very informative! I never thought the payment processor themselves would be doing it incorrectly, but that might explain why I was having such a hard time with it. Adding the charsetDecode(hmacHex,"utf-8") did the trick for matching our payment processor. I can now avoid using toBase64() since it has been depreciated. Much appreciated!

Comment: *that might explain why I was having such a hard time with it* That is what happens when you try and use logic in an illogical world ;-) Your original approach was the correct way to convert hex to base64. However, it being their API .. well .. the exact rules about the returned value are entirely up to them.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks @Leigh for such a detailed answer.